# Progress bar not shown during training, Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, progress, training-data

I'm trying to train a 2D Unet, for the segmentation task.
I execute this line of code:

```
model.fit(training_generator, epochs = params["nEpoches"],
                    validation_data=validation_generator, verbose = 1, use_multiprocessing = True, workers = 6, callbacks=[callbacks_list,csv_logger])
```

Where

- **training_generator** = Istance of `DataGenerator(x_training, y_train_flat, **params)`, with the image and the masks array as parameters of this class.
- **epochs** = 2
- **validation_generator** = Istance of `DataGenerator(x_validation, y_validation_flat, **params)`, with validation data.
- **callbacks_list** = `checkPoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='min', period=1)`
  `callbacks_list = checkPoint`

With the `verbose=1` parameter I think I should see a progress bar showing the training status for each epoch, but the only thing I see is `Epoch 1/2`, without any bar. So I can't say if the training process is going on or if it's stucked somewhere.

Comment: Try `verbose=10`, but anyway models from libraries never get stuck, they may compute long, but never get stuck.

Comment: It is likely because it does not know how much steps it should have for one epoch and accordingly show a progress bar. Check your batch size and try to specify ``steps_per_epoch`` in the ``model.fit()``

Answer (score 0):

According to Tensorflow documentation,

***steps_per_epoch:-***

> Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples) before
> declaring one epoch finished and starting the next epoch. When
> training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data tensors, the
> default None is equal to the number of samples in your dataset divided
> by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined. If x is a
> tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch will run
> until the input dataset is exhausted. When passing an infinitely
> repeating dataset, you must specify the steps_per_epoch argument.

***validation_steps:-***

> Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset.
> Total number of steps (batches of samples) to draw before stopping
> when performing validation at the end of every epoch. If
> 'validation_steps' is None, validation will run until the
> validation_data dataset is exhausted. In the case of an infinitely
> repeated dataset, it will run into an infinite loop. If
> 'validation_steps' is specified and only part of the dataset will be
> consumed, the evaluation will start from the beginning of the dataset
> at each epoch. This ensures that the same validation samples are used
> every time.

In your case, training progress is going on, as rightly mentioned by @Kaveh, it does not know how much steps it should have for one epoch and ran into an infinite loop. Check your `batch size` and add `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` to the `model.fit()` as shown below will resolve your issue.

```
model.fit(training_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = len(training_generator) // training_generator.batch_size,
    epochs = params["nEpoches"],
    validation_data=validation_generator, 
    validation_steps=len(validation_generator) // validation_generator.batch_size,
    verbose = 1, 
    use_multiprocessing = True, workers = 6, callbacks=[callbacks_list,csv_logger])
```

For more information you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)